# How to flip background image using CSS?

Tags: css, mobile-webkit

How to flip any background image using CSS? Is it possible?

currenty I'm using this arrow image in a `background-image` of `li` in css

[image]

On :`visited` I need to flip this arrow horizontally. I can do this to make another image of arrow **BUT** I'm just curious to  know is it possible to flip the image in CSS for `:visited`

Comment: good question! this could come in handy in a lot of different instances.

Comment: @AshBrad - Thanks for comments. yes it could be useful in many conditions

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I found I way to flip only the background not whole element after seeing a clue to flip in Alex's answer. Thanks alex for your answer

HTML

```
<div class="prev"><a href="">Previous</a></div>
<div class="next"><a href="">Next</a></div>
```

CSS

```css
.next a, .prev a {
    width:200px;
    background:#fff
}
 .next {
    float:left
}
 .prev {
    float:right
}
 .prev a:before, .next a:before {
    content:"";
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah0iN.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    display:inline-block 
}
 .next a:before {
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
    transform:scaleX(-1);
}
```

See example here http://jsfiddle.net/qngrf/807/

Comment: @Jitendra  Can you please check Jsfiddle URL. I think it is not having the same code you posted in your answer + its not working..

Comment: jsfiddle code you post is fliping text to? is it what you want, or just background image?

Comment: your jsfiddle is not the same as the code , can u please update it ?

Comment: @JitendraVyas hello from 2016! I was considering suggesting an edit to fix the jsfiddle URL as it still links to different code than is in your answer here - care to edit the post or remove the link? Thanks :)

Comment: `-webkit-transform:scaleX(-1);` for chrome

Answer (score 280):

You can flip it horizontally with CSS...

```
a:visited {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/btDKa/).

If you want to flip vertically instead...

```
a:visited {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    filter: FlipV;
    -ms-filter: "FlipV";
}
```

[Source](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/flip-an-image/).

Comment: If I'm only considering Web-kit browsers then only `-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);` is enough?

Comment: @Jitendra It should be, plus the non vendor prefixed property.

Comment: @alex - one problem in this. it's flipping the text also which is inside the `<a>` and I only want to flip the background image. The code you give is to flip the whole element

Comment: @Jitendra It doesn't look like you can just flip the background image. You could place the icon in a `span` and then flip that, however.

Comment: @alex - OK the if i use this code `<li><a href="#"><span>text</span></a></li>` it's flipping the text too so what will be opposite of your give code to unflip the text so i can write unflip code for `li a span {  }` in css

Comment: @Jitendra You wouldn't do it that way, you'd put the icon in the span and do `a:visited span { ... }`.

Comment: @alex - Please edit your jsfiddle example. I don't want to keep blank `<span> </span>` though.

Comment: @Jitendra If you don't want to make the compromise, you won't get it working in today's browsers.

Comment: @alex- I'm only considering web-kit browsers. is it possible without using blank `span`?

Comment: @alex - I found a way without compromise. Thanks to you to give me a clue.

Comment: Also yay for [XY flipping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale); `transform: scale(-1, -1);`, which is equal to `transform: scale(-1);`.

Comment: @Claudio you didn't made any improvements to the answer in your edit. I don't know why some one approved this edit.

Comment: You can also apply `transform: scaleX(-1);` on all children elements to undo the mirroring for anything besides the background >:D

Answer (score 27):

According to w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

> The transform property is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, and Opera.
>   Internet Explorer 9 supports an alternative, the -ms-transform property (2D transforms only).
>   Safari and Chrome support an alternative, the -webkit-transform property (3D and 2D transforms).
>   Opera supports 2D transforms only.

This is a 2D transform, so it should work, with the vendor prefixes, on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, and IE9+.

Other answers used :before to stop it from flipping the inner content. I used this on my footer (to vertically-mirror the image from my header):

HTML:

```
<footer>
<p><a href="page">Footer Link</a></p>
<p>&copy; 2014 Company</p>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
background:url(/img/headerbg.png) repeat-x 0 0;

/* flip background vertically */
-webkit-transform:scaleY(-1);
-moz-transform:scaleY(-1);
-ms-transform:scaleY(-1);
-o-transform:scaleY(-1);
transform:scaleY(-1);
}

/* undo the vertical flip for all child elements */
footer * {
-webkit-transform:scaleY(-1);
-moz-transform:scaleY(-1);
-ms-transform:scaleY(-1);
-o-transform:scaleY(-1);
transform:scaleY(-1);
}
```

So you end up flipping the element and then re-flipping all its children. Works with nested elements, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This one worked best for me, since the others either flipped all the children too or required a more complex trick to reverse the flip.

Comment: If this answer does flip everything inside of your targetted element, just push it down into another element. In other words, wrap the content you do not want to be flipped inside of a new <div> element.

Answer (score 13):

For what it's worth, for Gecko-based browsers you can't condition this thing off of `:visited` due to the resulting privacy leaks.  See http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Answer (score 6):

You can flip both vertical and horizontal **at the same time**

```
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
```

And with the **transition** property you can get a cool flip

```
    -webkit-transition: transform .4s ease-out 0ms;
    -moz-transition: transform .4s ease-out 0ms;
    -o-transition: transform .4s ease-out 0ms;
    transition: transform .4s ease-out 0ms;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: .4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0ms;
```

Actually it flips the **whole** element, not just the `background-image`

**SNIPPET**

```js
function flip(){
 var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
 if (myDiv.className == 'myFlipedDiv'){
  myDiv.className = '';
 }else{
  myDiv.className = 'myFlipedDiv';
 }
}
```

```css
#myDiv{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  padding:90px;
  background-color:red;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-transition:transform .4s ease-out 0ms;
  -moz-transition:transform .4s ease-out 0ms;
  -o-transition:transform .4s ease-out 0ms;
  transition:transform .4s ease-out 0ms;
  transition-property:transform;
  transition-duration:.4s;
  transition-timing-function:ease-out;
  transition-delay:0ms;
}
.myFlipedDiv{
  -moz-transform:scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
  -o-transform:scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
  -webkit-transform:scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
  transform:scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Some content here</div>

<button onclick="flip()">Click to flip</button>
```

Comment: The "flip both vertical and horizontal at the same time" has the same effect as turning the image 180 degrees, works fine and is what I was looking for,