# Is it possible to repeat the background image in html mirrored horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, dom

The background customer gave us has 4:3 aspect ratio and looks horrible when repeated on modern screen. I thought if I can mirror each repeat horizontally it would look nicer. Is this possible with plain CSS?

Comment: There is no CSS option to *reverse* a background image if that's what you are asking.

Comment: It may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768998/how-to-flip-background-image-using-css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768998/how-to-flip-background-image-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

Not with background images. You can mirror single elements, but not a part of a single element (as a background image is).

I guess the best option would be to save the image including its mirrored version into one graphic file and repeat this one.